# Cannot break out of a for loop in C

Tags: c

I spent some time on this but I can't figure out why it's not exiting the for loop.

```
for (int i = 1; i < rows - 1; i++) {
     printf("before copy\n");

     copyArray(rows, columns, table, temp);
     printf("after copy\n");

           for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
              printf("inside j\n");
              if (table[i][j] == xOrO && table[i + 1][j] == xOrO && table[i - 1][j] == '.') {
                  temp[i - 1][j] = xOrO;
                  if (guessTwoMoves(rows, columns, temp, xOrO, playerPiece)) {
                      copyArray(rows, columns, temp, table);
                      return ('A' + j);
                  }
              }
           }

     printf("before break\n");
     printf("%i \n", i);
           if (i == 4) break;

     printf("inside i\n");
}

     printf("outside 3rd");
```

This is what I get: The `i = 4` but it doesn't exit the loop for some reason Check the image to see the output. I am still not used debugging in the terminal so I used print statements. Please check the picture below

[Output after debuging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qCzF.png)

Comment: Why do you think it is not exiting the loop? The last thing I see in your output is `4`, which should be the `printf` right before the `break` statement.

Comment: The `printf` statement outside your outer loop (the one with `"outside 3rd"`) doesn't have a newline in it, so it might be still in the IO buffer. Add a newline there or flush the output buffer to see it. If that's not the problem, we'll likely need some more context.

Comment: Carl Norum, Thanks for pointing it out. after adding the new line it seems that it did exit the loop. I ll try to see what's wrong with it

Comment: OK; I'll see if I can find a question to dupe this one to.

Comment: Thanks again, I fixed the problem. I was stuck as I thought that the problem was in that loop. I didn't know that I had to add a new line to take out of the buffer

Answer (score 0):

From what I see is that the "Inside i" is missing on the image that you have shared so the loop actually got terminated.

As for the `printf` outside of the loop, see the comments to your post.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I have missed the one and considered that to be outside of the scope of the text snippet. My bad... Post got corrected now.